# Is it possible to track a google map location using landline phone number?

Tags: google-maps

I want to locate a location on the google map using phone number. Is it possible? If yes, what is the parameter which I need to append in the request url. As of now, I am appending 'address' and my URL is

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=THE+FRENCH+LAUNDRY&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, this is not possible with Google Maps (but maybe someone else knows more...). In some country, like Italy (where I live), it could even be against the law (depending on a few legal parameters).

Despite this, I saw some user here in SO signalling that some applications developed and managed by Google and installed on Android devices seem to be able to do so (in the countries where this is legal, of course). Most likely, these apps use a Google online database that is not accessible to the common user/developer.

Moreover, there are other companies that offer location services that can locate a user both if he/she uses a cellular phone and if he/she uses a land line one (in the countries where this is legal).